# Calling a function inside a function in python3

Tags: python, function, class, python-3.x

I have a class and am trying to create a function inside of a function in the class. My code is this:

```
class example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.points = 0
    def operations(self):
        def add(self):
            self.points += 1
        def subtract(self):
            self.points -= 1
    def display(self):
        print(self.points)

obj = example()
obj.display()
obj.operations.add()
```

I get the output *0* and then get the error:

```
obj.operations.add()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'add'
```

I have tried many other ways to solve this but none have worked.
Please answer if you know how to fix this error.

-Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You can define functions inside of functions but they will not be available through `function1.function2`. Especially they don't even exist as long as you don't execute the function (and if you don't "save" the functions afterwards they will cease to exist).

Comment: Functions inside functions are *locals*, just like any other variable in a function. They only exist for the duration of a function call, and not outside that call. Did you want to namespace these functions for some reason?

Comment: @MartijnPieters The reason why I have a function inside A function is that In my actual program, I have lots of programs and I'm a person who likes to keep things neat.

Comment: @Nic: This is not making it neater. Deviating from common practices makes your code harder to maintain, for example. Functions can't be used to create an additional namespace, at any rate.

Comment: What else except `operations` are you going to implement on that object?

Comment: @MartijnPieters So, is it better of I just have all my functions all straight in the class and not try to have functions inside functions?

Comment: @Jasper I have moving functions in my class (def move_left ect.) and some other things. I was hoping I could have obj.movement.move_left.

Comment: @Nic instead of a function you could place an inner class. But I don't think that it would make it any cleaner but quite the opposite.

Comment: @syntonym I could use an inner class although I would need to be able to pass self through the class. If you know how to create an inner class and pass self through, then please provide an answer.

Comment: @Nic: prefix your operation functions if you have to; `instance.operations_add` and `instance.operations_subtract`. You can have a simple object that you create as an attribute that knows how to [bind methods to the original instance](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) but that's a lot of extra work and will only serve to obfuscate your code.

Comment: Do you see the redundancy in `obj.operations.add()` and `obj.movement.move_left()`? There is no need to state that `add` is an operation or `move_left` a movement.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you can try returning functions from the function then use them something like this -

```
class example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.points = 0
    def operations(self):
        def add():
            print "add is called"
            self.points += 1
        def subtract():
            self.points -= 1
        return [add, subtract]
    def display(self):
        print(self.points)

obj = example()
obj.display()
obj.operations()[0]()
obj.display()
```

If you specifically want to do it with `obj.operations.add()` you can try aggregation in this way (it involves the usage of class variable, if that's alright with you)

```
class example:
    points = 0
    def __init__(self):
        example.points = 0
        self.operations = Operations(self)

    def display(self):
        print(self.points)

class Operations(example):
    def __init__(self, ex):
        self.points = ex.points

    def add(self):
        print "add is called"
        example.points += 1
    def subtract(self):
        example.points -= 1

obj = example()
obj.display()
obj.operations.add()
obj.display()
obj.operations.subtract()
obj.display()
```

hope it may help !

Comment: I would still like to go "obj.operations.add()". But still, your way works and I'll use that way if I cant find any other way. Thanks!

Comment: if you return a named tuple you could get obj.operations().add. And if operations is a property, which returns a named tuple you would have obj.operations.add. But... don't do that.

Comment: The class example worked! Thanks!

Comment: The class example uses *class attributes*. Yes, it happens to work, but as soon as you use more than one instance you'll see shared data. Store the `example` instance in the `Operations` instance and reference `self.example.points` instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Could you provide an example?

Comment: @Nic try creating another `example()` object; `obj1` and `obj2` then play with one and call `display` on the other.